# Customize save() method in Spring Roo

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aspectj, spring-roo

I've made an application with Spring Roo (I'm still a newbie) and I'd like to do some processing after the entity is persisted. I've set up the application with Service and DAO layer. In the service I created a custom method called triggerChange(MyEntity myEntity). I'd like that this method would be invoked after saving the entity but I don't know how could I call that method without modifying the *ServiceImpl_Roo_Service managed by Roo (which shouldn't be editted).

So I have a code like this one:

The service:

```
public class MyEntityServiceImpl implements MyEntityService {
    //this is the method I want to invoke inside or after invoking save()
    public void triggerChange(MyEntity myEntity) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The Aspect for the service:

```
privileged aspect MyEntityServiceImpl_Roo_Service {
    ...
    public void MyEntityServiceImpl.saveMyEntity(MyEntity myEntity) {
        myEntityRepository.save(myEntity);
    }

}
```

How could I customize save method?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have AspectJ enabled in your Spring application thanks to Roo. Just create an Aspect (after or around the method call)

You also can to move the methods from the *Roo* aspects (.aj)

> In STS select the desired methods (and even attributes) from the aspect class, right click, refactor->push in... and press Review-OK or OK directly (I recommend the former in order to review the changes)
>
> Another way: with Roo running, just create a method/attribute with the same signature in the class. Roo will remove the equivalent from the aspect.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is, to use the JPA or Hibernate events.

Have a look a this [blog](http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=600) (the author is a very active SO User), it explains how Spring Beans can be use for such events.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah good idea but I'd like something more general because this method couldn't be used for customizing the finders created by Spring Roo

Comment: @Javi: Finders? your question was about saving! Anyway there are events for loading too.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had to perform some business logic after a save method, just like you wanted.

Let's say I have to log that a save operation has been performed. For doing so, I've created this aspect:

```
package com.malsolo.aspects;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import com.malsolo.myproject.domain.MyEntity;

aspect MyEntityAspect {

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyEntityAspect.class);

    pointcut persistEntity() : execution(* MyEntity.persist(..));

    public Logger getLogger() {
        return logger;
    }

    after() : persistEntity() {
        logger().info("Entity persisted "+thisJoinPoint);
    }

}
```

It writes:

> 2011-11-30 11:47:27,056 [main] INFO 
>   com.malsolo.aspects.ModifyRolAspect - Entity persisted execution(void
>   com.malsolo.myproject.domain.MyEntity.persist())

I hope it helps you.

Notes:

- I'm using Roo 1.1.5 with the @Entity approach, I have no service layer
- Pay attention to the import of the Entity. It wouldn't work
  without it.
- If you use STS with AJDT, you'll see the advises applied.